# eShopOnContainers reference application for Java developer

Tags: java

I am looking for a complete reference application likes https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers of .NET but is implemented using Java and related technologies.

It would be great and helpful for Java developers if someone or organization convert .NET eShopOnContainers to Java eShopOnContainers.